# vue3 (scirpt setup) use ref<InstanceType<typeof XXX>>() report an error

Tags: vuejs3

Here's the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRPPZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7Pd.png)

Comment: Please do the tour to learn how to format code. Include code and output as text, not as images!

Answer (score 1):

`Script setup` is not exposed by default in subcomponents, if you need to use the sub-component you need to use the `defineExpose` API, like this:

```js
export interface XXXAPI{
  loginAction:typeof loginAction
}

const loginAction = ()=>{
  // do something
}

defineExpose({
  loginAction
})
```

parent component:

```js
const accountRef = ref<XXXAPI>();


const handleClickLogin = () =>{
  accountRef.value?.loginAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Ref`

```
import { Ref } from "vue"

const accountRef = Ref<InstanceTyp<typeof LoginAccount>>()
```